# Recursion and line execution

Tags: java, recursion

I understand how recursion works, but in this case does anything ever print?

```
void foo(int num) {
     if(num < 1) 
       return;
     foo(num - 1);
     System.out.println(num);
 }
```

Say we let num = 5, then the if-condition is not met and we send 5 into foo(5-1) and so on. When, if ever, do we execute the print line?

Comment: nvm I just ran it on eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The `println` line is executed after the recursive call to `foo` returns.  A print from one recursive call won't print until the recursive call from one level down has a chance to print its line and end.

Because it won't print if `num < 1`, the first number to printed will be `1`, followed by `2`, and so on, until the original `num` (e.g. `5`) is printed.  Nothing will be printed if the original `num` was `0` or if it was negative.

Answer (score 0):

When num reaches 0 (i.e. `foo(0)` is called), the recursion ends, so after  `foo(0)` returns, 1 is printed. Then `foo(1)` returns and 2 is printed, and so on.